# ¿Cómo guardar PDF generado con FPDF en servidor externo?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, servidor, fpdf

Estoy generando PDF para cada registro de una tabla de mi BBDD, y en local estos PDF funcionan correctamente.
El funcionamiento es el siguiente: el cliente da clic en un botón para generar el PDF. En el backend, recibo los datos necesarios para el documento y estructuro al mismo, para luego guardarlo con un nombre dado por varias variaables concatenadas y devuelvo estas variables para poder abrirlo desde JS en el frontend.
En local esto funciona sin ningún problema, pues los documentos generados se guardan dentro de la carpeta especificada, pero en mi servidor externo no recibo nada más allá de las variables concatenadas como respuesta, pues el documento no se guarda dentro de la carpeta marcada, cuando en local funciona correctamente.

Dejo por acá el código del PDF para mayor entendimiento:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT, GET, DELETE, POST");

require('../plugins/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

// create document
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

// add text
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 20);
$pdf->Cell(0, 10, 'YORAA SAC', 0, 1);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
$pdf -> Ln();
$pdf -> Cell(90, 10, utf8_decode('Cliente: ' . $data -> data -> name), 0);
$pdf -> Cell(100, 10, utf8_decode('C贸digo: ' . $data -> data -> code), 0, 0 , 'R');
$pdf -> Ln();
$pdf -> Cell(20, 15, utf8_decode('Fecha: ' . $data -> data -> date), 0, 1);

$pdf -> Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode('Producto'), 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode('Cantidad'), 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode('Precio Unit.'), 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode('Precio Total'), 1, 0, 'C');

$pdf -> Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);

$sub = 0;
foreach($data -> products as $p) {

    foreach($p as $product) {

        $pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode($product -> name_product ), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode($product -> quantity), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode($product -> unit_price), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode($product -> quantity * $product -> unit_price), 1, 0, 'C');
        $pdf -> Ln();

        $sub += $product -> quantity * $product -> unit_price;

    }

}

$pdf -> Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
$pdf -> SetY($pdf -> GetY() + 5);
$pdf -> SetX(90);
$pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode('Total'), 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf -> Cell(40, 10, utf8_decode($sub), 1, 0, 'C');

// output file
$pdf->Output('F', 'https://yoraasac.com/'. $data -> data -> name . '-' . $data -> data -> date . '-' . $data -> data -> code .'.pdf');
echo $data -> data -> name . '-' . $data -> data -> date . '-' . $data -> data -> code;
```

Comment: Revisa los permisos de la carpeta donde estás intentando guardar los archivos.

Comment: Tengo todos los permisos activos. El código es 777.

Comment: Sale algo en los logs de PHP? Y, si entiendo bien, pones como salida una URL? No debería ser una ruta en el servidor????? O es una ruta FTP?

Comment: En los logs no hay errores. He probado como ruta y como URL y ninguna funciona.